# How to get the sum if there is more than one record of a particular data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

[image]
Code:

```
select 
    ID
    User_ID
    FINAL_SETTLEMENT
    EASEMENT_AREA
    EASEMENT_AREA_COST
    EASEMENT_AREA_PERCENT
from tblpaymentnegotiations where user_id = 69
```

**Note: the user ids are all different in this table. I'm using this one as an example**

This scenario I've given is done on the UI and there's a panel where users can insert payment negotiations for a particular piece of land that they own. In this case, I have easement area and I want to know: How to calculate a sum if there are multiple/more than one records in the panel for the **Final Settlement column**? So say `ID 2` wasn't there to begin with and just had `ID 1` If I create a new record in that panel and put in the numbers for it, save it, a new ID/record `(ID 2)` will be added to the table. Same applies if other users add more easement numbers, since every user_id is different and unique. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Look up basic aggregation regardless of which DBMS you are using. They ALL work the same. Something like SUM(Final_Settlement) group by User_ID

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the sum of the final_settlement by user_id.

```
SELECT 
     User_ID
    ,SUM(FINAL_SETTLEMENT)
FROM tblpaymentnegotiations
GROUP BY User_ID
```

If you're trying to keep a "running" final_settlement in the table itself, that's probably not a good idea - every time a record gets inserted, you're potentially updating many records in the table.  Instead, create a view using the above SELECT query.

Comment: What do you mean by "running" in this case?

Comment: As in, if you're hoping to keep a column in the table that gets updated whenever a new row is inserted (potentially updating several rows per insert)

Answer (score 0):

For a SQL server 2008 and above version the optimal query will be like

```
select 
    ID,
    User_ID,
    SUM(FINAL_SETTLEMENT) OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID) as FINAL_SETTLEMENT,
    EASEMENT_AREA,
    EASEMENT_AREA_COST,
    EASEMENT_AREA_PERCENT,
from tblpaymentnegotiations where user_id = 69
```

Note that the above query returns all rows.
If you need only final rows then use below query

```
select * from 
    (select 
        ID,
        User_ID,
        SUM(FINAL_SETTLEMENT) OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID) as FINAL_SETTLEMENT,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY ID DESC) as rownum,
        EASEMENT_AREA,
        EASEMENT_AREA_COST,
        EASEMENT_AREA_PERCENT,
    from tblpaymentnegotiations where user_id = 69) t
where t.rownum=1
```